# How to stop a shutdown and do something with Powershell on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, shutdown

I would like to create a script that detect and delay a shutdown on Windows 10 PC's and show a Message if a USB-Stick is plugged in at the moment of the shutdown.

My problem is that my script is not stop the shutdown. Im pretty new to Powershell. Sry for my english.

This is what i got:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.Management, Version=2.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")

$Man = New-Object System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_USBHub")
[System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection]$Devs = $Man.GetInstances()

$global:shuttingDown = $false
$sysevent = [microsoft.win32.systemevents]
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $sysevent -EventName "SessionEnding" -Action {$global:shuttingDown = $true; Write-Host "  SessionEnding"} 
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $sysevent -EventName "SessionEnded"  -Action {$global:shuttingDown = $true; Write-Host "  SessionEnded"} 

do {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        if ($global:shuttingDown) {
            & "$env:SystemRoot\System32\Shutdown.exe" -a ;

            $Devs | ForEach-Object {
            if($_.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString() -eq "USB-Massenspeichergerät"){

                Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
                $ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::Ok
                $MessageboxTitle = “USB-Stick gefunden”
                $Messageboxbody = “Es wurde ein USB-Stick gefunden. Nicht vergessen mitzunehmen ;)”
                $MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Warning
                [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($Messageboxbody,$MessageboxTitle,$ButtonType,$messageicon)

                Write-Output ""
                Write-Output $_.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString()
                Write-Output ""
            }
            $Devs.Dispose()
            $Man.Dispose()
        }
    }
    Write-Host "  Waiting for Shutdown"
} while ($true)
```

thx for your help

Comment: why are yo checking the $global:shuttingDown in if condition??? you dont need it cause you are setting it externally.

Comment: I got this form a script where the powershell prevent the shutdown, and i thoug this i a way to check for the system shutdown...i see what you mean that makes no sense. I wanna check if the system shutdown, but i cant find a way to check that. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I am not understanding why are you checking `if ($global:shuttingDown) {}`. Because it will receive true or false and in both the cases, the condition will results in true. You can't post some script taken from somewhere without understanding the logic. There is a logical error which stops you to hit the `& "$env:SystemRoot\System32\Shutdown.exe" -a ;`

Comment: You check a shutting down even in a do while and if the result is true then abort it else loop it.

Comment: Ok. You're right i dont really understand the code. I'm sorry for that. I just cant figure out how to check if a user shutdown the pc and run my code before the pc shutdown. I thought this code allow me to check this. I wanna do this for my school, because so many people forget the usb-sticks. I was hoping to find some finished scripts for that. Do you  know what code i need in my if statement to show the messagebox before the pc shutdown?

Comment: Thats alright. Give me some time . Meanwhile you can go through Server Vault link for it [Prevent Shutdown](http://serverfault.com/questions/379830/powershell-window-preventing-shutdown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so basically, if $global:shuttingDown holds value then use a **Break**

```
do {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    if ($global:shuttingDown) {break}
    Write-Host " Waiting for Shutdown"
} while ($true)
```

Comment: Ok, First thank you for you help! I really appreciate it. So, if i run this code...i see in de console "Waiting for Shutdown" a few times. But if i shutdown my pc it shutdown normal. I cant get it to abort the shutdown.

Comment: @damiguel : great .. Accept the answer if it helps  you

Comment: It seems you are very familiar with powershell. Can you maybe provide me the complete code to abort a shutdown from local users? Then i will accept the answer. I dont get it to work. Maybe it was not my best idea because im not familiar with powershell. I thought this is very easy to do.

Comment: @damiguel: Sure. But let me go through it completely . I am from mobile. I will spare some time on it on Monday. SO you basically needs to abort the shutdown and stop the USB via powershell right?

Comment: Yes i need to abort the shutdown and show a message that still a usb stick is pugged in. The problem is that i need it today, but i understand if there is no way to do that. If i dont get any other solution i will accept your answer tomorrow. Anyway thank for your help and time!

Comment: @damiguel : Its 22:21 here. And tomorrow, family going out. I would be from mobile mostly.